# Is it possible to connect to a PostgreSQL server using FreeTDS driver and tsql?

Tags: postgresql, t-sql, odbc, freetds

I've asked this question on serverfault and someone told me to ask here.

Can I make a connection to a PostgreSQL server using FreeTDS, more specifically using the `tsql` command?

I've been trying for a few days now, using many different configurations. Even though I am able to connect to the DB using `isql` and PostgreSQL odbc driver, I can't make it work using `tsql` (it also doesn't seem to use `odbc.ini` or `odbcinst.ini`). So, I was wondering if the `tsql` command only works with SQL Server.

If you want, I can post the files freetds.conf, odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini.

Thanks.

Comment: What is this `isql` thing? The postgres command line client is `psql`. What exactly are you trying to do? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: T-SQL works with the databases that support it - Sybase and SQL Server

Comment: Also: "*make a connection using a T-SQL command*" does not make _any_ sense. A SQL statement can only be executed if you _have_ a connection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, when I install freeTDS it installs some executables, such as `isql` and `tsql` (as you can see here http://www.freetds.org/userguide/confirminstall.htm). I am trying to use something like `tsql -S sname -U user` to connect to a postgresql db.

Comment: That's what `psql` is for. Why do you try to use tools that are for a **completely** different database? `psql` is already installed with your Postgres server. There are also many other SQL clients that you can use with Postgres that are not tied to SQL Server: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I understand. The thing is a client was writing some code using freeTDS libraries, such as libtds. If he can't use the same code to connect to the postgresql db, he will have to rewrite stuff.

Comment: @brunodea: yes, that's what needs to be done. Each database has it's own protocol. You can only do this somewhat database independent if you use a layer like JDBC or ODBC.

Comment: Just for clarity, `tsql` is for connecting/testing the FreeTDS connect to SQL Server/Sybase. `isql` is for connecting/testing the unixODBC layer of the stack (and FreeTDS in turn, since it is further up the stack).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FreeTDS only supports the TDS protocol (hence the name). And this protocol is only implemented by Microsoft SQL Server and the Sybase database.

So, no you can **not** use FreeTDS to connect to a Postgres database.

You need to use the [Postgres ODBC driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/), the [Postgres .Net driver](http://www.npgsql.org/) or the [Postgres JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/) to do this - depending on the programming language of your application. From a C program you can also connect to Postgres directly [using the libpq library](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html).

Comment: I was actually trying to connect using the command line `tsql -S sname -U user` (as seen here http://www.freetds.org/userguide/confirminstall.htm).

Comment: @brunodea: then use `psql`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html what you are trying to do makes no sense at all at will never work.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking. Thank you!